# MySQL Group BY with priority on which grouped record to return

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, group-by

I have the following two tables:

```
Products
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                       | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| productName              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| landColour               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Skus
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| product_id   | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| colour       | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| fit          | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| size         | decimal(10,1) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| stock_status | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| image        | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Product Data
+----+--------------+------------+
| id | productName  | landColour |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 1  | Running Shoe | Red        |
| 2  | Smart Shoe   | Green      |
| 3  | Casual Shoe  | Blue       |
+----+--------------+------------+

Sku Data
+----+------------+--------+--------------+------+--------------+----------------+
| id | product_id | colour | fit          | size | stock_status | image          |
+----+------------+--------+--------------+------+--------------+----------------+
| 1  | 1          | Red    | Standard Fit | 5    | In-Stock     | /img/img1.jpg  |
| 2  | 1          | Green  | Standard Fit | 5    | In-Stock     | /img/img2.jpg  |
| 3  | 1          | Blue   | Standard Fit | 5    | In-Stock     | /img/img3.jpg  |
| 4  | 1          | Red    | Standard Fit | 6    | Out-of-Stock | /img/img4.jpg  |
| 5  | 1          | Green  | Standard Fit | 6    | In-Stock     | /img/img5.jpg  |
| 6  | 1          | Blue   | Standard Fit | 6    | In-Stock     | /img/img6.jpg  |
| 7  | 2          | Red    | Standard Fit | 5    | Out-of-Stock | /img/img7.jpg  |
| 8  | 2          | Green  | Standard Fit | 5    | Out-of-Stock | /img/img8.jpg  |
| 9  | 2          | Blue   | Standard Fit | 5    | Out-of-Stock | /img/img9.jpg  |
| 10 | 2          | Red    | Standard Fit | 6    | In-Stock     | /img/img10.jpg |
| 11 | 2          | Green  | Standard Fit | 6    | Out-of-Stock | /img/img11.jpg |
| 12 | 2          | Blue   | Standard Fit | 6    | In-Stock     | /img/img12.jpg |
| 13 | 3          | Red    | Standard Fit | 5    | In-Stock     | /img/img13.jpg |
| 14 | 3          | Green  | Standard Fit | 5    | In-Stock     | /img/img14.jpg |
| 15 | 3          | Blue   | Standard Fit | 5    | In-Stock     | /img/img15.jpg |
| 16 | 3          | Red    | Standard Fit | 6    | In-Stock     | /img/img16.jpg |
| 17 | 3          | Green  | Standard Fit | 6    | In-Stock     | /img/img17.jpg |
| 18 | 3          | Blue   | Standard Fit | 6    | In-Stock     | /img/img18.jpg |
+----+------------+--------+--------------+------+--------------+----------------+

Desired Results
+------------+--------+--------+------+----------------+
| product_id | sku_id | colour | size | image          |
+------------+--------+--------+------+----------------+
| 1          | 1      | Red    | 5    | /img/img1.jpg  |
| 1          | 5      | Green  | 6    | /img/img5.jpg  |
| 2          | 10     | Red    | 6    | /img/img10.jpg |
| 3          | 15     | Blue   | 5    | /img/img15.jpg |
| 3          | 18     | Blue   | 6    | /img/img18.jpg |
+------------+--------+--------+------+----------------+
```

I am trying to retrieve all skus where `fit = 'Standard Fit'` AND `stock_status = 'In-Stock'` grouped by size but if the skus.colour field matches the products.landColour column then that is my preferred record. The aim is so that for each product I will have a sku record for every size that is in stock and preferably the same colour as the land colour. This is what I have tried which is almost right but not quite, some records aren't being returned even though they are in stock:

```
SELECT 
    p.productName AS name, 
    p.id AS product_id, 
    IF(s1.size IS NULL, s2.size, s1.size) AS size, 
    IF(s1.image IS NULL, s2.image, s1.image) AS image, 
    IF(s1.fit IS NULL, s2.fit, s1.fit) AS fit 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN skus s1 ON 
    p.id = s1.product_id 
    AND s1.stock_status = 'In-Stock' 
    AND s1.colour = p.landColour AND 
    s1.fit = 'Standard Fit' 
LEFT JOIN skus s2 ON 
    p.id = s2.product_id 
    AND s2.stock_status = 'In-Stock' 
    AND s2.fit = 'Standard Fit' 
GROUP BY size 
HAVING ( image IS NOT NULL AND size IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment391934_333952

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: I've added some sample data and desired results now

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully follow what you are trying to do.  However, this is highly suspect:

```
GROUP BY size
```

I suspect that you want:

```
GROUP BY p.productName, p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do with a SINGLE join and add a column to indicate your "preferred" entries.  Then your order by could be based on all the preferred pushed to the top and all others following.  In this case, for each product, I just have a flag if the preferred color is found, it gets a 1 (for later sort), otherwise 2 come after #1 preferred.

```
SELECT 
      p.productName AS name, 
      p.id product_id, 
      s1.size, 
      s1.image, 
      s1.fit,
      if( s1.colour = p.landColour, 1, 2 ) as PreferredFlag
   FROM 
      products p 
         LEFT JOIN skus s1 
            ON p.id = s1.product_id
           AND s1.stock_status = 'In-Stock' 
           AND s1.fit = 'Standard Fit' 
   GROUP BY 
      size,
      if( s1.colour = p.landColour, 1, 2 ) as PreferredFlag
   HAVING 
          image IS NOT NULL 
      AND size IS NOT NULL
   order by
      if( s1.colour = p.landColour, 1, 2 ),
      size
```

Now, you are not doing any aggregations that would really warrant a group by except by size and that is just resulting in the first product name and ID for any given size that qualifies.  You might actually need to adjust to something like below.  In this case, I am getting a SUM of the count that match the color desired as a preferred flag COUNTER.  but also have a COUNT of how many of a given product name and size actually are available, regardless of the color.

The final ORDER BY is based on...  If the total count of matched color is > 0, then it gets a 1, otherwise 2 for sort purposes, THEN sorted by size.

```
SELECT 
      p.productName AS name, 
      p.id product_id, 
      s1.size, 
      s1.image, 
      s1.fit,
      COUNT(*) as NumberAvailable,
      SUM( if( s1.colour = p.landColour, 1, 0 )) as PreferredFlag
   FROM 
      products p 
         LEFT JOIN skus s1 
            ON p.id = s1.product_id
           AND s1.stock_status = 'In-Stock' 
           AND s1.fit = 'Standard Fit' 
   GROUP BY 
      p.productName
   HAVING 
          image IS NOT NULL 
      AND size IS NOT NULL
   order by
      if( SUM( if( s1.colour = p.landColour, 1, 0 )) > 0, 1, 2 ) as PreferredFlag,
      size
```